# UWP - Saving Tabs From The TabView class

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, event-handling, uwp-xaml

how do I save the data (tabs) created by the end user to reopen the tabs when the UWP application is closed.

---

#### Source Code - NavigationView Eventhandlers

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace Network
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>

    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();


        }

        private void NavigationView_OnSelectionChanged(NavigationView sender,
            NavigationViewSelectionChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args.SelectedItemContainer.Tag.Equals("Users"))
            {
                Frame.Navigate(typeof(Interface));

            }

            if (args.SelectedItemContainer.Tag.Equals("Interception"))
            {
                Frame.Navigate(typeof(Network));
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Does the following solve your problem? Any updates for this thread?

Answer (score 0):

> how do I save the data (tabs) created by the end user to reopen the tabs when the UWP application is closed.

Sure, you could save the Tabs data as json string, then store in the local folder during the app closing. When you reopen the app, you could deserialize the json string to the tab's data.

For example

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    App.Current.Suspending += Current_Suspending;
}
private ObservableCollection<TabData> Tabs;
private void Current_Suspending(object sender, Windows.ApplicationModel.SuspendingEventArgs e)
{
    if (Tabs.Count > 0)
    {
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Tabs);
        ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["TabsData"] = json;
    }

}
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    var json = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["TabsData"] as string;
    if (json != null)
    {
        Tabs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<TabData>>(json);

    }
    else
    {
        Tabs = new ObservableCollection<TabData>();
        Tabs.Add(new TabData( "page1",  Type.GetType( "App19.TestPage")));          
    }
}


private void TabView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    (sender as TabView).TabItemsSource = Tabs;

}

private void TabView_AddButtonClick(TabView sender, object args)
{
    Tabs.Add(new TabData("newPage", typeof(TestPage)));
}

private void TabView_TabCloseRequested(TabView sender, TabViewTabCloseRequestedEventArgs args)
{
    Tabs.Remove(args.Item as TabData);

}
```

**Tab Class**

```
public class TabData
{
    public TabData(string header, Type frameType)
    {
        Header = header;
        FrameType = frameType;
    }
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public Type FrameType { get; set; }
}
```

**Xaml**

```
<muxc:TabView
    AddTabButtonClick="TabView_AddButtonClick"
    Loaded="TabView_Loaded"
    TabCloseRequested="TabView_TabCloseRequested">
    <muxc:TabView.TabItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <muxc:TabViewItem Header="{Binding Header}" >
                <muxc:TabViewItem.IconSource>
                    <muxc:SymbolIconSource Symbol="Document"/>
                </muxc:TabViewItem.IconSource>
                <Frame SourcePageType="{Binding FrameType}" />
            </muxc:TabViewItem>
        </DataTemplate>
    </muxc:TabView.TabItemTemplate>
</muxc:TabView>
```