# C# UWP MVVM inject a view inside another view

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp, uwp-xaml

Hi I have a xaml File where I have a NavigationView with NavigatioViewItems. Inside the NavigationView I have a ScrollViewer where I want to inject a view. This is the xaml:

```
<Page
    x:Class="ToolBoxApp.Views.AudioHomeView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:ToolBoxApp.Views"
    xmlns:viewmodels="using:ToolBoxApp.ViewModels"
    xmlns:mainview="clr-namespace:ToolBoxApp"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:i="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
    xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <!--<Page.DataContext>
        <viewmodels:AudioHomeViewModel/>
    </Page.DataContext>-->
    
    <Grid>
        <NavigationView x:Name="navigationViewControl" 
                        IsBackEnabled="true"
                        >

            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="ItemInvoked">
                    <core:EventTriggerBehavior.Actions>
                        <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding NavigateToTextToSpeechView}" />
                    </core:EventTriggerBehavior.Actions>
                </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

            <NavigationView.MenuItems>
                <NavigationViewItem Icon="MusicInfo" Content="Text to Speech"/>
                <NavigationViewItem Icon="MusicInfo" Content="Youtube to Mp3"/>
            </NavigationView.MenuItems>

            <ScrollViewer>
                <Frame x:Name="ContentFrame"/>
            </ScrollViewer>
    
        </NavigationView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

So far I have a NavigationService where I can navigate to different views:

```
    public class NavigationService : INavigationService
    {
        public void GoBack()
        {
            var frame = (Frame)Window.Current.Content;
            frame.GoBack();
        }

        public void Navigate(Type sourcePage)
        {
            var frame = (Frame)Window.Current.Content;
            frame.Navigate(sourcePage);    
        }

        public void Navigate(Type sourcePage, object parameter)
        {
            var frame = (Frame)Window.Current.Content;
            frame.Navigate(sourcePage, parameter);
        }

        public void NavigateScrollViewer(Type sourcePage, Type injectPage)
        {
            var frame = (Frame)Window.Current.Content;
            
            var page = frame.CurrentSourcePageType;
        }
    }
```

The NavigatScrollViewer method should implement this in a generic way because the whole app will use it. I will have different Windows like the xaml file above where I want to inject views into the ScrollViewer Frame. Is there a way to get a reference to this ScrollViewer inside code and then setting its Frame to the view I want to specify through the NavigationService?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please check the following, does it work?

Comment: Yes it works basically but the Binding seems not to work although I have a OnPropertyChange trigger in the setter. Refer to this question of mine where I asked how to attach different Commands to different MenuItems. In the answer you can see how I solved it. In the OnItemInvoked Method I dont use the NavigationService anymore I just set my property with the corresponding view type. When I debug it I can see that the binded property changes but it doesnt reflect on the UI. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68102232/c-sharp-xaml-set-commands-for-different-menuitems-inside-a-navigationview

Comment: Ok solved: Needed to use Mode=TwoWay. Silly me is going to read now what these things mean...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> C# UWP MVVM inject a view inside another view

If you have used MVVM design, you need to bind Frame `SourcePageType` property with ViewModel's page type property. you just need to update this page type property, the Frame content will be update.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67362883/7254781) is sample code that you could refer.

> Is there a way to get a reference to this ScrollViewer inside code and then setting its Frame to the view I want to specify through the NavigationService?

the other way is pass `ContentFrame` instance to `NavigationService`. At first you need add new frame property for NavigationService class. And then replace your code frame with `MyFrame`.

```
public class NavigationService
{
    private Frame MyFrame { get; set; }
    public NavigationService(Frame frame)
    {
        MyFrame = frame;
    }
}
```

**Usgae**

```
 var navService = new NavigationService(ContentFrame);
```

For above design is referring [Windows Template Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WASTeamAccount.WindowsTemplateStudio) `NavigationService`, it is complete implementation, and you could find the `NavigationService` initialization process in the shell page.

```
ViewModel.Initialize(shellFrame, navigationView, KeyboardAccelerators);
```

Comment: You are the best! This was literally the last puzzle piece that I had to figure out. Works like a charm!